# Sequential Compactness: Show that there exists a number $\alpha$ and a sequence of positive integers $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Here's the problem:

Consider the function $f(x)=\text{cos}(\sqrt{x}e^x)$. Show that there exists a number $\alpha$ and a sequence of positive integers $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ such that

$$ \lvert f(a_1)-\alpha \rvert \lt 1, \lvert f(a_2)-\alpha \rvert \lt \frac{1}2,\lvert f(a_3)-\alpha \rvert \lt \frac{1}3,... $$

(Hint: remember the definition of sequential compactness and apply it to $[-1,1]$.)

Here is the definition of sequential compactness from my lecture notes:
"A set $S \subset \Bbb R$ is sequentially compact if ANY sequence in $S$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $S$."

So, I know that a set is sequentially compact iff the set is closed and bounded. I also know that the outputs of the given function are all, obviously, within the interval $[-1,1]$. There's also this idea that a subsequence can be created that converges to a point in the set, but I don't think that that applies here. Basically, I'm pretty lost on this one, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** what do you know about the sequence $(f(n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

**Hint 2:** note it says the *definition* of sequential compactness.

**Hint 3:** Recall the definition of convergence: a sequence $(f(n))$ converges to $\alpha$ if for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that
$$ \left| f(n) - \alpha \right| < \varepsilon. $$

So, we have a convergent subsequence from compactness. First take $\varepsilon=1$, and choose the first term of your sequence that satisfies
$$ \left| f(n) - \alpha \right| < 1, $$
and call this $a_1$. Now put $\varepsilon=1/2$...

Comment: Well, I know that it does not converge; it just oscillates between -1 and 1. EDIT: Actually, it never approaches -1 or 1, but it stays within that interval.

Comment: So it's contained in the (sequentially) compact interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: So, I thought that since it never reaches -1 or 1, it's not closed?

Comment: It's a bounded real-valued sequence. If I mention the names Bolzano and Weierstrass does that mean anything?

Comment: Well, yes, I know the Weierstrass theorem concerning global minima and maxima ("extreme value theorem," I think). I've $heard$ of Bolzano-Weierstrass, but have never been formally introduced to it. EDIT: But, of course, a quick Wikipedia search has changed that.

Comment: Okay then, what is your definition of sequential compactness (feel free to edit the question to include it)?

Comment: From my lecture notes: "Def: A set $S \subset \Bbb R$ is sequentially compact if ANY sequence in $S$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $S$." I'll put it in my OP, as well.

Comment: Right, so do you see what this has to do with the sequence $(f(n))_n$ and the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Well, the issue is that the sequence ${f(n)}_n$ doesn't converge, and thus certainly does not converge to a point in the set. Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: You have a sequence contained in an interval that is closed and bounded ($[-1,1]$, to be precise). Now, you stated "a set is sequentially compact iff the set is closed and bounded". Therefore you know that $[-1,1]$ is sequentially compact, right?

Comment: The interval $[-1,1]$ is most certainly closed and bounded, yes.

Comment: So I have a sequence in a sequentially compact set. The definition of sequential compactness then says I can do... what?

Comment: ...create a subsequence converging to a point in the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Exactly. You can find a subsequence that converges. The last step is to refine it to obey what the question wants: do you want a hint for that as well?

Comment: Right, I gathered that, by definition, such a number MUST exist, but assumed that I needed to find that number or give a more rigorous proof of its existence. A hint would certainly be appreciated; it would likely be a bunch of brute force trial-and-error for me otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

As you know, sequence $\cos n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. The same we can say about the sequence $\cos \sqrt{n}e^{n}$. Let $A$ be an image of $\mathbb{N}$ with function $f$. Let's apply the definition of dense set

$$ \forall \alpha \in [-1;1] \forall \varepsilon>0  \quad \exists a\in A: |\alpha-a|<\varepsilon   $$
and remember that 
$$\forall a\in A \quad \exists n\in \mathbb{N}: a=f(n). $$

Consider a sequence $b_k=\frac{1}{k}$ instead of $\varepsilon$. Then for each $b_k$ we find $a_k\in A$ which is also denoted as $f(n_k)$. Now it's left to substitute these variables to the definition of density and make sure that everything is true.

Comment: Hmm. I've actually never heard of a sequence described as "dense." I assume it's the quality described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second displayed statement is actually false: the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$, and I can find a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, but there are irrational numbers...

Comment: @Chappers, do you mean $\forall a\in A..?$

Comment: That's the one. Oh, hang on, wasn't reading. NVM. But on the other hand, I'm not convinced that this is what the question seems to want: nothing is mentioned about density and so on.

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude, you are right. But there is one more solution without the definition of dense set, this one was the most clear for me.

Comment: @Chappers, of course, I could have used a Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for a bounded set, and maybe it would be more acceptable :) 
but that solution above was the first idea which I came up with